# Fast sorted sample with replacement

Tags: r, performance

Basically, I want to do `sort(sample(n, replace = TRUE))`, for `n = 1e6`, and many times (e.g. 1e4 times).

Any way to do it faster in R(cpp)?

Comment: Doubtless it can be done faster in Rccp, but `sample(n, replace = TRUE))` does the heavy lifting, with most of the cpu cycles in efficient C routines, so I doubt that the improvement will be dramatic. One idea for improvement if to call `sample(10^10, replace = TRUE)` (assuming you have the RAM) then partition that vector into chunks of size `10^6`, sorting them as you go.

Comment: I believe that `sort` is taking for time than `sample` here.

Comment: isn't this the same as sampling from a uniform distribution? could do with runif() and cut() or findInterval()?

Comment: You could microbenchmark it. My rule of thumb is that the more R code sticks to built-in functions, the less room there is for rcpp improvement.

Comment: anyway, 1e6 and 1e4 are not very large numbers, it shouldn't take long to do this operation? you could easily swap out the lapply() of replicate() for a parLapply()

Comment: @MichaelChirico Since `findInterval()` does a binary search (I believe) I don't think that using `runif` and `findInterval` is an efficient way to generate samples for a discrete uniform distibution, especially when the sample size is something like `10^6`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Unfortunately, `runif` is not faster than `sample`.

Comment: if sort is the bottleneck, you should run sort as few times as possible (10^10 may not fit in memory, but 10^7 or 10^8 usually does)

Comment: If you are sorting less than `2^31 ==  10^9.33` numbers, use `sort.int(x, method = "radix")`.

Comment: with such a specialized routine in mind, definitely Rcpp has room for substantial improvement. the following approach would be hard to replicate in base: at index 1, sample from 1:n. thereafter, sample between the previous value and n. if you reach n, pad the rest of the vector. would need to think a bit more carefully but I believe this is equivalent and would be more efficient

Comment: Making the full vector seems redundant vs just counting each time each number is repeated, like `rmultinom` does. Similarly, you could tabulate instead of sorting (the tabulation contains the same information) `rmultinom(1, n, rep(1/n, n)); tabulate(sample(n, replace=TRUE))`

Comment: @Frank Nice idea! Would even make it faster using Rcpp. I'm trying to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Frank in the comments, it makes sense to use `tabulate` instead of `sort`. Once one uses that, it makes sense to think about [faster sampling methods](https://blog.daqana.com/en/fast-sampling-support-in-dqrng/) as provided by my [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dqrng) package:

```r
library(dqrng)
m <- 1e6
bm <- bench::mark(sort(sample.int(m, replace = TRUE)),
                  tabulate(sample.int(m, replace = TRUE)),
                  sort(dqsample.int(m, replace = TRUE)),
                  tabulate(dqsample.int(m, replace = TRUE)),
                  check = FALSE)
bm[, 1:4]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   expression                                     min   median `itr/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                                <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>
#> 1 sort(sample.int(m, replace = TRUE))         72.3ms   75.5ms      13.2
#> 2 tabulate(sample.int(m, replace = TRUE))     22.8ms   27.7ms      34.6
#> 3 sort(dqsample.int(m, replace = TRUE))       59.5ms     64ms      15.3
#> 4 tabulate(dqsample.int(m, replace = TRUE))   14.4ms   16.3ms      57.0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that I am still using R 3.5 on this machine. With R 3.6, the difference between `sample.int` and `dqsample.int` would be larger. Note also that one no longer needs a development version of dqrng to get the fast sampling methods.

One can also use the RNGs from dqrng via C++, but that does not make much difference compared with `tabulate(dqsample.int(...))` in my experience:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(dqrng, sitmo)]]
#include <dqrng_generator.h>
#include <convert_seed.h>
#include <R_randgen.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector sort_sample(uint32_t n) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector seed(2, dqrng::R_random_int);
    auto rng = dqrng::generator(dqrng::convert_seed<uint64_t>(seed));
    Rcpp::IntegerVector tab(n);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint32_t k = (*rng)(n);
        tab[k]++;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the issue of `sample()` being biased?

Comment: @F.Privé See https://blog.daqana.com/en/dqsample-a-bias-free-alternative-to-rs-sample-function/ and https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17494.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing @Frank's idea in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector sort_sample(int n) {
  IntegerVector tab(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int k = n * unif_rand();
    tab[k]++;
  }
  return tab;
}
```

Benchmark:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort(sample(n, replace = TRUE)),
  tabulate(sample(n, replace = TRUE), n),
  sort_sample(n)
)
```

For n = 1e5:

```
Unit: microseconds
                                   expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
        sort(sample(n, replace = TRUE)) 3214.726 3393.606 3667.1001 3507.0525 3716.3560 7007.411   100
 tabulate(sample(n, replace = TRUE), n) 1087.543 1104.215 1245.0722 1136.9085 1218.5865 4265.075   100
                         sort_sample(n)  789.403  812.780  870.2723  837.3445  924.4395 1188.432   100
```

For n = 1e6:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
        sort(sample(n, replace = TRUE)) 49.96651 52.58784 61.19775 55.09312 58.43035 160.16275   100
 tabulate(sample(n, replace = TRUE), n) 13.74391 14.44253 17.22742 15.99816 17.54367  48.72374   100
                         sort_sample(n) 12.80741 14.40371 17.98320 15.31699 17.53548  63.21692   100
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran a small example with `rmultinom`, which I expected to be faster. I guess because the number of possible values is large relative to the length of the vector (both length n), it is slow... not sure.

Comment: @Frank I will adapt this idea to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `n * unif_rand()` is biased, which is why R 3.6 contains a new (slower) method. My `dqrng` package provides [faster sampling  methods](https://blog.daqana.com/en/fast-sampling-support-in-dqrng/).

Comment: @RalfStubner Nice to know. I would be happy to accept your solution if you provide a better solution.